# JWT API token storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, sequelize.js

I'm writing the API part of an application and am working on the authentication using JWT. I'm now simply generating a token and when the user is created sending the token back in a json object for the front-end to deal with. But is this correct? Shouldn't I put the token into the header on the back-end side? Since when I want to log out the user I want to access the token in the header and delete it from the back-end side...

Thankful for any response

Comment: Keep in mind, that even if you "log out" user can still continue the session if he manually copied the JWT That's why JWT aren't really that good as session tokens.

Comment: I know, I would need to create a blacklist database so that the tokens can not be used again

Comment: You don't need a database, you can just put a life span on the token for it to expire and in your JSON object response put expiry time in ms and creation time so it can easily be calculated on the front-end. When it expires, you request a new token..

Comment: Okay, but just to be clear. I'm only supposed to send the token from the back-end not put it in the header or anything like that? That's done in the front-end? Then that would mean that the clearing of the token from the header when logging out also is done in the front-end?

Comment: It doesn't really matter where it's done, you can put it in cookies if you want. Using blacklist completely defeats the purpose of JWT, you should probably be just using sessionID in cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies to store the JWT,
 When the JWT token is stored in a cookie, the browser will automatically send it along with each request to the same domain.

> If you are using nodejs, The best way to store JWT token in
>   cookie-session

Advantage of cookie-session: cookie-session variable do not delete while restarting server or doing modifications on code